# Linkedin Sign In doesnt work on Apple devices using Javascript SDK

Tags: linkedin-jsapi

I have used Javascript SDK method for sign in my application, and it works on all devices and browsers expect for the Apple devices.

However, on Apple Devices auth modal opens and when I click on sign In it redirects to the previous page

How can i sign my Apple Apps using Javascript SDK

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The [LinkedIn JavaScript SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) is not compatible with iOS 5+.

You will need to use Rest API to Sign In on LinkedIn if you want to do it with JavaScript.